# How to Lock the Screen When Rotation at 270 on Android

Tags: android, screen-rotation

I've got an application , I want to lock the screen when I pressed a button.
So I want to know how can I set the screen rotation to 270.
The application use android 1.6(API 4).So I can't use

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
```

When the screen is landscape and orientation!=Surface.ROTATION_90.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can't do this on API 4.
You can only use SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE from API 9.

Comment: After years finally I got an answer.And yes U r right,I can't achieve the goal on API 4.THANKS.